# How to apply lm with variables from different datasets

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply `lm()` using multiple variables from different datasets.

For example, suppose I got two datasets: A and B as below,

```
A
date        vision
2001-01-01    1020
2001-01-02     923
2001-01-03    1019
2001-01-04    1010
2001-01-05    1013
...
...
2015-12-31    1025

B
date         site  dust
2001-01-01     1     50
2001-01-01     2     45
2001-01-01     3     56
2002-01-02     1     47
2002-01-02     2     85
2002-01-02     3     78
...
...
2015-12-31     1     65
2015-12-31     2     98
2015-12-31     3     88
```

I tried to see a relationship between `vision` and `dust`.

So I input

```
reg <- lm(A$vision ~ B$dust)
```

and get an error message

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = A$vision ~ B$dust, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : different length..

In addition, I tried to merge two datasets into one with

```
M <- merge(A, B[,c(1,3)], by="date")
```

but it did not work.

How can I fix this to apply `lm()` function to see an association between those variables?

Comment: Your merging variable has different names between the two data sets. You can use `by.x` and `by.y` to specify the correct names in this case.

Comment: @James Thank you for your comment. I edited typo in the data to prevent a further confusion.

Comment: Keep in mind that autocorrelation violates the OLS assumption of uncorrelated errors. So `lm` might not be the best idea...Try `gls` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Once you merged:

```
M <- merge(A, B[,c(1,3)], by="date")
```

You can perform

```
reg <- lm(M$vision ~ M$dust)
```

If you don't do that, you can't except the model to find the merging key by himself....